# Sign in as someone else in AWS Cognito

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito

i'm using Cognito for user authentication on a site I'm working on for a client, and I need to add (if possible) a way for an admin (of the site) to login as a user. It's mainly used to see issues that the user is experiencing.

Do you know if there's a way to do that with Cognito, basically signing in as someone else if you have a specific code or belong to a specific group, or any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not *easily*.

Effectively Cognito doesn't want you to be able to do this, as it opens no end of security issues within your application.

*However*, you can take control of the authorisation process by using [Custom Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html). By writing your own custom authentication, you can effectively allow user impersonation so long as the authenticating user can pass your authentication "tests".

I'd invite you to think hard about this method, however, as it does mean that you are now responsible for making sure no one else can use this backdoor.

Comment: I agree, I was checking just in case the client insisted, but we ended up not needing to go down that path

Comment: It seems to be this is a use-case a lot of people need, strange that this is not a feature of cognito

Comment: Its not really strange, its good practice. You should not confuse authentication with authorisation. Cognito deals in the former. You should instead create an admin role at the application level which allows more advanced permissions. Cognito authentication will therefore remain unchanged.